# .Net Maui Blazor Hybrid (Debugger Tool/ Console Tool)

Tags: maui, maui-blazor

I am trying to use debugger or console to change my desktop app to different screen size, In the console window I don't see the option to change to different windows size like we normally see with console windows on browsers. I have written css for designing, I need to write media query for different sizes, how can I do so?

Change the desktop application to different screen size.

Answer (score 0):

There is no method to change the window size in the .css file. You can check this document about how to [change the window size in Maui Blazor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/windows?view=net-maui-8.0#position-and-size-a-window).

You can override the CreateWindow method to change the window size. Here is the code you can refer to.

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    public App()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override Window CreateWindow(IActivationState activationState) =>
        new Window(new AppShell())
        {
            Width = 700,
            Height = 500,
            X = 100,
            Y = 100
        };
}
```